# remove the first html tag in a string

Tags: php

i have this text

```
<?php
   $example1 = '<b class="counter">1</b> This is a computer';
   $example2 = '<b class="counter">5</b> i have a laptop';
   $example3 = '<b class="counter">1</b> i need a smartphone';
   $example4 = 'i need a car'; // does not have <b> tag
?>
```

i'm looking for a php function to remove a part of the string, starting from `<b>` to `</b>`, so the results should be like :

```
$example1_result = 'This is a computer';
$example2_result = 'i have a laptop';
$example3_result = 'i need a smartphone';
$example4_result = 'i need a car';
```

Comment: use strip_tags($example1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to escape from your "counter" otherwise it will not work, but the others have already answered your question with a better version using regular expressions.

```
<?php
$example1 = "<b class=\"counter\">1</b> This is a computer";
$example2 = "<b class=\"counter\">5</b> i have a laptop";
$example3 = "<b class=\"counter\">1</b> i need a smartphone";

echo strip_tags($example1); //Outputs: 1 This is a computer

$example1 = trim(substr(strstr($example1, '</b>'), strlen('</b>')));
echo $example1; //Outputs: This is a computer
```

Comment: the second solution is exactly what i was looking for, strip the first b tag including its content, thank's a lot. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace("(<([a-z]+)>.*?</\\1>)is","",$example1);
```

use this as you want to remove the content inside the `<b>` tags also `strip_tags()` will keep the content inside the html tags

Comment: Ah yeah this would probably be better +1

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `strip_tags` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

it essentially strips, well tags from the string:

```
<?php
    $htmlStr = '<p>Text</p>';
    $str     = strip_tags($htmlStr);

    var_dump($str); //will echo Text
```

Comment: You should understand the question before answering. -1

Comment: You have misunderstood question

Comment: @Zaki, no need to be rude, one could also say you should search before asking a question.

Comment: @zaki in my defence I generally interpreted the question to mean it wanted html tags stripped, it's harder to understand when it seems clear in one way, if you get my meaning :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the result after  you can use `substr($example, strpos($example, '</b>'))` where $example is `<b class="counter">1</b> This is a computer`